# Incorrect back behaviour in Stack Navigator inside Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have nested a Stack Navigator containing multiple screens in Top Tab Navigator. When inside stack navigator, back swipe gesture instead of navigating within Stack screens navigates to previous screen of top Tabs. Navigation Structure:

```
Top Tabs:
  Screen 1: Botton Navigator
  Screen 2: Stack Navigator:
    Screen 2.1
    Screen 2.2
```

I require navigation from 2.1 to 2.2 then when I do back swipe gesture I want to navigate back to 2.1 but it navigates to Screen 1.
When I am at screen 2.2 shouldn't the current or child navigator i.e. Stack navigator handle back gesture. Can someone please help regarding this.

Comment: Can you post how BackHandler is used?
Do you use reset ?

Comment: It is default back swipe gesture of IOS

Comment: Can you post your sample code?
Or check my sample -> https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/bottom-navigation-example

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to resolve it. Child navigator takes care of the gesture but the gesture area of stack navigator was set to default value = 25 which was more than swipe area of Top Tab Navigator. Increasing gestureResponseDistance in stack navigator screen options did the job for me.